# Metrizable + LCH Space that is not 2nd Countable/Separable?

Tags: general-topology

Does there exist a locally compact hausdorff space that is metrizable but not 2nd countable/separable?

This comes from an exercise in Munkres' textbook, on Urysohn's metrization theorem, which states that 2nd countable regular spaces are metrizable. Unfortunately, all of the examples of nonseparable metric spaces I know (basically $l^\infty(\mathbb{R}))$ are not locally compact so I can't use them as counterexamples. At the same time, I'm not sure how to furnish a proof of the result above.

Comment: Now that I think of it - would an uncountable disjoint union of $[0,1]$s work?

Comment: any uncountable discrete space works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions like these can be answered by $\pi$-Base: [π-Base, Search for `Metrizable+Locally Compact+~Separable`](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Metrizable%2BLocally+Compact%2B%7Esep)

As noted in the comments, any uncountable disjoint union of metrizable locally compact spaces is such an example.